# XSLT: How to change an attribute based on conditions

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XSLT example:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="elements/element">
      <xsl:if test="@type='OUTPUT-TEXT'">
        <div data-order="{order}" class="output">
            <xsl:if test="style/left_align = 'true'">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">ml-lg</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="style/right_align = 'true'">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">mr-lg</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            ...
            <xsl:value-of select="value" />
        </div>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to add some classes to "class" attribute based on conditions.

So if I have this xml:

```
<elements>
   <element type="OUTPUT-TEXT">
      <order>1</order>
      <value>Hi!</value>
      <style>
         <left_align>true</left_align>
         <right_align>false</right_align>
      </style>
   </element>
</elements>
```

I expect something like this:

```
<div data-order="1" class="output ml-lg">Hi!</div>
```

I have several Booleans and I must evaluate all and add classes because of them, and I must respect the previous classes that I have into.

Comment: What should the result look like when two (or more) style elements are true?

Comment: @michael.hor257k For example: if `<left_align>` and `<right_align>` are true, the class attribute must contain `class="output ml-lg mr-lg"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `xsl:attribute` to create an attribute, it will overwrite any existing attribute already created the same name.

Try this way instead

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="elements/element">
      <xsl:if test="@type='OUTPUT-TEXT'">
        <div data-order="{order}">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:text>output</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="style/left_align = 'true'">
                    <xsl:text> ml-lg</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="style/right_align = 'true'">
                    <xsl:text> mr-lg</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="value" />
        </div>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This worked if only one Booleans are true, if I get 2 true values, this code only write first.

Comment: Are you sure? See http://xsltransform.net/ehVYZNE/1 for an example when both values are true. In this case, both class names are included in the class attribute.

Comment: I had an error in the syntax, thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/elements">
   <xsl:for-each select="element[@type='OUTPUT-TEXT']">
        <div data-order="{order}">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:text>output</xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="style/*[.='true']"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="value" />
        </div>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="left_align"> ml-lg</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="right_align"> mr-lg</xsl:template>
<!-- add more templates here -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```